# UILabel with dynamic width - Horizontal Alignment

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

I have an UILabel in a custom cell class in an UITableView and I use the following code to increase the width of the label dynamically in regards of its content:

```
CGSize sizeToMakeLabel = [cell.cellResult.text sizeWithFont:cell.cellResult.font];

cell.cellResult.frame = CGRectMake(cell.cellResult.frame.origin.x, cell.cellResult.frame.origin.y, sizeToMakeLabel.width, sizeToMakeLabel.height);
```

The problem that appears using the above code, is that I can no longer have the label to be right aligned (increase the width of it to the left instead of right).

If I don't use the above code and set alignment to right in IB, the alignment works. But in this case, I lose the dynamic width.

I've tried with:

```
cell.cellResult.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRigth;
cell.cellResult.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

but nothing happens.

Can someone help me out on this one please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't right align the label because you set its real width for its frame.

If you want it to be dynamic but right aligned, you can do something like:

```
CGSize sizeToMakeLabel = [cell.cellResult.text sizeWithFont:cell.cellResult.font];

cell.cellResult.frame = CGRectMake(cell.cellResult.frame.origin.x + cell.cellResult.frame.size.width - sizeToMakeLabel.width, cell.cellResult.frame.origin.y, sizeToMakeLabel.width, sizeToMakeLabel.height);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you change the origin of the label when setting it's frame:`cell.cellResult.frame.origin.x,`

You could change the bounds to manage the width only.

Answer (score 2):

you can set frame for your label like :

```
[self.lblTitle setFrame: CGRectMake(self.lblTitle.frame.origin.x,
                                    self.lblTitle.frame.origin.y,
                                    [self.lblTitle.text sizeWithAttributes:
                                     @{NSFontAttributeName:
                                           self.lblTitle.font}].width,
                                    self.lblTitle.frame.size.height
                                    )];
```

it will work